# Send Multiple Remote Desktop Sessions A Command

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop

I use [Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989) to administer users on my network.  I am looking for a way, or another program, that will allow me to send a command to all of my logged in remote connections at once.  So if I am connected to 10 PCs, I can send them all a command to run a batch file, or maybe start a program.  Something like `\\server\folder\run.bat`.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Questions: 1) Do I correctly assume the list of computers you're remotely connected to could be different at any given time? 2) Would you be able to come up with a list of the computers to which you wanted to send the command *without* involving the RDP Manager?

Comment: Yes, the computers could be different.  And Yes, I could generate a list of computers that I wanted the command send to.

Comment: Are the computers on the same LAN or on different networks? Also, do you have Administrative level access to the computers?

Comment: They are on the same domain, on the same LAN, and yes, I would be logged in as domain admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the same command simultaneously on multiple computers using [PSEXEC.EXE from Microsoft's SysInternals toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). To run a command on multiple remote computers:

1. Create the text file `PCNAMES.TXT`
2. Put the remote computer names in the text file, one per line
3. Run PSEXEC.EXE using the following syntax:
   `PSEXEC.EXE @PCNAMES.TXT -s Command_To_Run.exe`

This will run `Command_To_Run.exe` in the context of the remote computer's SYSTEM account and it assumes the executable is in the system path on the remote machine.

**PSEXEC command line options relevant to your situation:**

```
-c         Copy the specified program to the remote system for execution. If you omit this
           option the application must be in the system path on the remote system.
-d         Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).
-u         Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
-p         Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this you will be prompted
           to enter a hidden password.
-s         Run the remote process in the System account.  The remote command will only
           have access to local resources on the remote computer.
```

**Examples:**

1. Copy `Command_To_Run.exe` from your local computer to the remote PC (`-c` switch) then execute it there:
   `PSEXEC.EXE @PCNAMES.TXT -c Command_To_Run.exe`
2. Use a different user account/password (`-u` and `-p` switches) to run the remote command.  Useful when accessing network resources from the remote PC:
   `PSEXEC.EXE @PCNAMES.TXT -u UserName -p Password Command_To_Run.exe`

Comment: To get PSEXEC.EXE to work, I had to running the command prompt as the domain admin.  Holding shift + Right click on the CMD launcher, and selecting run as different user.