# Starting a steam game remotely using powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell

I am trying to start Space Engineers using this command saved in a .ps1 file:

```
Start-Process -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\SpaceEngineers\Bin64\" -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\SpaceEngineers\Bin64\SpaceEngineers.exe"
```

When I run this on the local computer, it works as expected and starts the game.

When I try to run this remotely (from another computer, having the same .ps1 file), nothing happens, no output from console, program successfully exists.

This command worked both locally and remotely:

```
taskkill /F /IM SpaceEngineers.exe
```

I am invoking remotely like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName x.x.x.x -filepath "myscript.ps1" -credential xxx
```

Any idea where to look or what could this be caused by? I am pretty experienced with Linux and Mac if it matters, but I have almost 0 experience with PowerShell.

Comment: The remote console is not likely to be attached to a desktop session. I suspect you actually need to use `Psexec -i -d <command>` to run as an interactive session. See https://superuser.com/questions/734642/how-to-run-a-program-on-a-remote-pc-via-command-line. Apparently `Invoke-Command` does not support running an interactive program https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/db1f6a16-c584-4604-bbe1-fe3d4f20bc5f/is-there-a-way-to-make-invokecommand-interactive?forum=ITCG.

Comment: Essentially the remote machine you connect to is running the command you give it as a standalone user that is not attached to the logged in session. It is isolated and does not have a "desktop". What you need to do is connect to the desktop session and ask *that* user to run your command, rather than just telling the *system* to run a command.

Comment: Also related: https://superuser.com/questions/925297/send-multiple-remote-desktop-sessions-a-command which also suggests that psexec is the right tool.

Comment: Thank, I will check that out!